# Sending email through PHP mail function not working for long emails

Tags: php

I am trying to use the php mail function to send emails from my site. Users on the site type their emails in an html form. I have tested the mail functionality and it works when the email text is small such as:

```
this is an email
```

However, when I type a long email, the `mail()` function returns `1` but no email is actually received. The code to dispatch email is simply:

```
$email_message = $_POST['email_mssg_from_form'];
$ret = mail($to, $subject, $email_message);
```

I have tried to regularize contents of `$email_message` using:

```
$email_message = wordwrap($email_message, 70, "\r\n");      
$email_message = addslashes($email_message);
```

but this didn't help. I am not sure how else to handle quotes and long lines. Normally when a user types an email on a form, there will be continuous lines of text and only paragraphs will be separated by `\r\n`

Comment: `$email_messaage` contains the value of the `POST` variable, but you are using `$email_message` to send into the `mail()` function. Is this correct, or a typo?

Comment: check your mail server log then read this -:http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html there are a lot of posibilites to rule out

Comment: But server is sending emails when the mail message is not long and complex. So something wrong with the way i am handling $email_message string.

Comment: How do you know that the message is not sent even if it's long and complex? Perhaps the receiving client is blocking it for spam reasons. I can see why, if you added lorem ipsum phrases some other word combination that repeats itself :)

Comment: the 1 from the mail server just means it was accepted by the local mailserver, nothing about delivery or any other mailservers response to the email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had similar problem where the length of the message was causing inconsistencies. This is what did the trick for me:

Use this line to encode your entire message using base64:

```
$email_message = chunk_split(base64_encode($email_message));
```

Then, add a header to the mail append this your header:

```
$headers = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
```

That will tell the mail client that your message is base64 encoded.

You will have to modify the call to the mail() functio as follows:

```
mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: I tried this but it did'nt work for me for long emails.